# What is the difference between return statement and defer.resolve in $http(req) in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have observed two different varieties of $http(req)  in production code.

```
sampleApp.factory('BrandService', function($http, $q) {

    var BrandService =  {};
    var BrandList = [];

    BrandService.GetBrands = function() {
        var Info ={};       
        Info.Action = "GET";
        Info = JSON.stringify (Info);

        var req = {
            url: BrandURL,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: Info
        };

        if ( BrandList.length == 0 ) {
            return $http(req).then(function (response) {
                BrandList = response.data
                return BrandList;
            });
        }
        else {
           return $q.when(BrandList);
        }
    }
    return BrandService;
});

sampleApp.factory('BrandService', function($http) {

        var BrandService =  {};
        var BrandList = [];

        BrandService.GetBrands = function() {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'BrandURL',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            data: "action=GET"
        };  
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http(req).then(function(response) {
            BrandList = response.data
            defer.resolve(BrandList);
        }, function(error) {
            defer.reject("Some error");
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
});
```

In one they are using return statement directly, in other they are using defer.resolve. I want to understand the difference between two?

Are they both same? If not, which one to prefer when?? Also why they are not handling error in first case?

Comment: This is a very good question...

Answer (score 1):

Both return promises, but the 1st one (`return $http(req)`) is the better option.

Look it this [article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) to see common promises mistakes, and the solutions.

The 2nd one is used to manipulate the data, and resolve / reject a new promise, but it should be converted to a promises chain like the 1st, because every resolved promise return a new promise with it's resolved value.

Instead of this:

```
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http(req).then(function(response) {
        BrandList = response.data
        defer.resolve(BrandList);
    }, function(error) {
        defer.reject("Some error");
    });
    return defer.promise;
```

Do this:

```
    return $http(req).then(function(response) {
        return response.data
    }, function(error) {
        return $q.reject("some error");
    });
```

Comment: Actually you will need to do a `return $q.reject("some error");` otherwise it wouldn't come in as a failure.

Comment: Thanks @MrHaze, missed that.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Affectively they are both the same, only difference is that:

In the first example you're wrapping the value of the promise in itself by returning it inside.

In the second example you're creating a new promise and wrapping the value of the first promise in the new one, and returning the new one instead.

---

### Overview

Angular's [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) returns a promise, the `.then()` **resolves** that promise.

---

### Some examples

Lets take this as an example:

```
// this is in data/users.json
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "Nikola Tesla",
        "specialty": "Electricity"
    },{
        "name": "Chris Hadfield",
        "specialty": "Space"
    }]
}
```

First lets discuss a bare promise:

```
function allUsers() {
    return $http.get('data/users.json');
}

allUsers().then(function (response) {
    console.debug(users);
    /*
        output:

        response: {
            header: {....},
            data: {
                "users": [....]
            },
            status: {.....}

        }
     */
});
```

as seen [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage)

Then lets return from the promise:

```
function allUsers() {
    return $http.get('data/users.json').then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}

allUsers().then(function (users) {
    console.debug(users);
    /*
        output:

        "users": [......]
     */
});
```

Here you're returning the value from within the promise so when it gets resolved, the value you returned would be the success value of that promise.

The deffered promise would return the same as returning directly from inside, the difference is that you resolve the first promise then you extract the value, wrap it in another promise, in this case you would be returning the differed -new- promise that you just created.

BTW, you **can** get the promise errors if you return directly from it like this:

```
function allUsers() {
    return $http.get('data/users.json').then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        return $q.reject({msg: 'there is an error here', error: error});
    });
}

allUsers().then(function (users) {
    console.debug(users);
    /*
        output:

        "users": [......]
     */
}, function (error) {
    console.debug(error);
    /*
        output:

        "msg": 'there is an error here',
        error: {.....}
     */
});
```

---

### My 2 cents

I prefer going with the first example (returning from within the promise) simply because:

- It's easier to read.
- You don't need to get messy with creating a new promise.

However, you can use both interchangeably, so go nuts with either!

**Moral of the story**

Both [Criss Hadfield](https://twitter.com/cmdr_hadfield) and [Nikola Tesla](https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/g8nl33fps74yf31lku4t.jpg) are awesome, and they both get the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case the service will only make an $http request if BrandList is empty, otherwise it returns the list. The second case will always make an $http request. In both cases a promise is returned.

Request errors are not not handled in the first case since the second parameter in .then() was not defined like in the second.

While both get the job done, it seems the first is a better since it doesn't make additional http calls once BrandList has been filled. One note though, the first case might still make multiple http calls until one of them resolves. Also if BrandList is actually zero, it will always make an http call.